# Android activity goes black then crashes

Tags: java, android

I recently started developing apps, and I've gotten my first gig.  It's a simple app with a logo and a button linking to a website.  Everytime I run it, it crashes, and I'm stumped as to why, as it's such a simple program.  I've spent a lot of time looking for similar problems on SO, but to no avail.  I've also gone through eclipse and eliminated any compiler warnings.  Does anyone have an idea as to what could have gone wrong?

Error messages:

[image]

I've kept cutting things out over and over to the app's most simple function. It still won't work.  Here is my .java and main activity.  (It's a one activity and one class app)

```
//necessary imports are omitted.  I get no errors for imports

public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            goToUrl("http://switchemup.com");
        }
    });

}

private void goToUrl(String url) {
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
    startActivity(launchBrowser);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fullscreen, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/switchuplogo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="94dp"
    android:text="View Website" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "and crashes" Is there anything in logcat about the type of crash?

Comment: @StevenV I've been having trouble using the emulator so I just built the apk and installed it on my phone.

Comment: You should still be able to use adb to connect to the device with your apk, and view the logcat. [More information in the documenation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)

Comment: @StevenV http://imgur.com/EYRRXU4   You're right.  Please excuse a dumb high schooler!

Comment: I think @Fllo is onto something in his answer. The stack trace there is saying `findViewById()` is throwing a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @whrobbins Taking Fllo's answer into consideration your code works on a device.

Comment: I see nothing else wrong except the `findViewById` method. Your button1 has the right id and there is nothing weird in your code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);` should create an error and this should cause the crash you app. You set a variable which contains a method that should be in `onCreate` method.

Try this instead:

```
// init your variable only
Button button;

// Then in onCreate, as you already did:
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    // set findViewById method only here
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
    // ...
}
```

Let me know if this helps.